# The name of the tag [white] should be changed to [white noise]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Hay, I'm not quite to 20,000 and so I cannot edit tags independently yet.  Can someone with more rep than I have or a moderator, can someone change the tag [white](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white) to be `white noise`?  This tag is used in about 5 different questions.

Perhaps we need to create a tag `white noise`, then for all questions using the [white](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white) tag, editing the tags of those questions, changing it to the newly-created `white noise` tag.  Then delete the [white](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white) tag.

Also the tag [stochastic](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic) should be marked as a synonym to the tag [random-process](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-process).

Answer (score 4):

Done, I think.

[image: Result of merge of tags.]

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Now I hope someone will accept my user-guidance for it.  Or write your own.

Comment: And I think that tag `white` should be eliminated.